# Laravel authentication getting the wrong user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a Laravel 5.6.20 application where I use authentication with username and password (instead of email and password) since, for internal reasons, some users have the same email address.

The authentication was configured properly to use username (the name of my field is actually 'code') as follows:
**LoginController.php**

```
public function username()
{
    return 'code';
}
```

The authentication is working fine. What is strangely happening is that, when a user who has the same email as another user logs in, he is authenticated as this other user. For example:

**User A:** 
code: 12345 
email: test@test.com

**User B:** 
code: 98765 
email: test@test.com

*User A authenticates using his credentials (12345 + password) and is directed to User B's page.*

Any thoughts about what is happening here? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.6.20 @JairoNavaMagaña

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set the code and email field unique.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have this option. =(

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to authenticate users, with their user names instead of email. However, laravel, authenticate users with email as default.
To change that, you should go to
vendor/laravel/framework/scr/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/AuthenticateWithBasicAuth.php
and you see in handle method :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null, $field = null)
    {
        $this->auth->guard($guard)->basic($field ?: 'email');

        return $next($request);
    }
```

You can change the 'email' field to the 'user_name' field that exists in your database.
This class (AuthenticateWithBasicAuth) exists in routeMiddleware in the middleware kernel.php class.

Comment: Hi @smhlotfizadeh, thanks for pointing me to the right direction. However I am using the $request on my handle method  in the Middleware, so I should be working properly, right?

`public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }

            return redirect()->guest(route($guard . '::auth.index'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }`

Comment: I think it should work properly, but you have to add ->basic($field ?: 'user_name') to authenticate your users according to their user_names.

Answer (score 0):

I got such problem. Authenticator returned wrong users. Users have **GUID as ID**. The issue was to add

`protected $keyType = 'string';`

into User class. That indicates to laravel not to transform string GUID to integer ID.